# How to update/insert contacts using JSforce for a chrome extension?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, bulkinsert, bulkupdate, jsforce

Am I able to update and insert contacts using JSforce? I am building a chrome extension with JavaScript that will push data from a Google sheet into SFDC. I have yet to find any good resources that show the queries that might be involved, I have only seen account updates/inserts.